# How to use a pytest fixture in a test (or method) automatically?

Tags: python, pytest

Given the info I found [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html), I tried the following:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver")
class TestSuite(object):
    def test1(self):
        driver.log("Start the test")
```

But I get an error

```
NameError: global name 'driver' is not defined
```

So the information is incorrect, or do I misunderstand it?

How to use fixtures automatically in each test method (or any other method) inside the `TestSuite` class?

**More information:**

- I need the fixture to be initialized anew for each and every test
- Normally a test required maybe 5 fixtures. But since I am using some methods for each test, I need to pass them all on like this

  ```
  def do_something(self, fixture1, fixture2, fixture3, fixture4, fixture5):
      ...

  def test1(self, fixture1, fixture2, fixture3, fixture4, fixture5):
       do_something(fixture1, fixture2, fixture3, fixture4, fixture5)
  ```

  Maybe it will not be quite that bad, but if I can use the fixtures automatically per test, that would help...

Comment: You can't. Note that `pytest` works with `unittest`-style tests in compatibility mode - tests that can be run with `unittest` can also be run with `pytest`, but don't expect `pytest` features to be always available for them. If you want to use `pytest` extensively, sooner or later you will have to rework the tests to functions as `pytest` expects them to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`usefixtures` means that the listed fixtures will be called automatically, not that they will be available in your code for you to call them.

I doubt there is a way to use a fixture without explicitly naming it.

```
class TestSuite(object):
    def test1(self, driver):
        driver.log("Start the test")
```

is the only way.